How do we know the final jurors in a case are actually random citizens of the county and not preassembled ,hired by the state to convict ppl and
How do we know for sure the jury isn't a group hired by state to convict ppl? I know nobody who ever served period. Not random citizens!do u know anybody who served, not summoned?

I know there's real ppl on here and the contradictory can be ppl who are in on it and will defend by trying to debunk or say they have seen or know someone  who was just a random citizen. And FYI it isn't random ppl. They interrogate them , the d.a and  the defense, and they keep or dismiss depending on their point of views. For example if it's a domestic violence case, they are looking to keep mostly women,whom maybe been victims of dv themselves .If the person is Hispanic they may refrain from selecting other Hispanic jurors. Males who been women's victims of dv. Random? I Don't think so..,

You seem to be making a claim that isn't falsifiable.  Is there any evidence that someone here could offer, that would convince you?  Or will you simply assume that they are just another agent of this purported conspiracy?

In many jurisdictions, including the US, most parts of most trials are open to the public. In high-profile cases, there will be more press and ordinary people than there are seats in the room, but becoming a spectator in an ordinary case is easy -- every citizen should do that some day, to learn how the system works. Mostly this will be extremely boring to people who have no relation to that particular case, however.
Keep in mind that circumstantial evidence is evidence. Say there is a room with one door and no windows. A bunch of witnesses say that there was a bundle of cash on the table when they left, that it was gone when they looked again, and that only one person entered the room in the meantime.
It could be that the witnesses are all lying to frame the suspect. So the defense would question if they benefit from their testimony, or if they may all be shielding the true culprit. But if those witnesses are found credible by the jury, then this circumstantial evidence would be enough to convict.

I’ve been summoned 3 times and I know two people who served
I don’t think they were part of a of a deep state conspiracy, and I’m certain I’m not.
But then, that’s what I’d say if I was part of a deep state conspiracy.
